# How to populate listview with database data inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I started to use fragments since I got comfortable with using activitys and I just wanna take things to a another level. What I learned so far is passing data between fragments and now I wanna try to do something which includes databases.

This is just an example app which will show me how to deal with this kind of stuff.

So basically I have a fragment for adding contacts and a second fragment to show the first name of the contact in a listview. I'm adding the contacts in a database and that part works fine. But when I try to show the data from a database inside a fragment that contains a listview my app gets crashed.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Contacts_Add.sendData {

DatabaseHandler handler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    handler = new DatabaseHandler(this, null, null, 1);

    //____________________________PRINT DATABASE_____________________

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Contacts_All(), "allFrag");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    Contacts_All fragAll = (Contacts_All) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("allFrag");
    fragAll.printDatabase();

    //______________________________________________________________________

//etValues method is outside of onCreate I just didnt put the whole code.

  @Override 
public void etValues(String fname, String lname, String phone, String email) {

    ContactsObjects contact = new ContactsObjects(fname, lname, phone, email);

    handler.insertContact(contact);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Contacts_All(), "allFrag");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    Contacts_All fragAll = (Contacts_All) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("allFrag");
    fragAll.printDatabase();


}
```

All contacts fragment:

```
public class Contacts_All extends ListFragment {


DatabaseHandler handler;

public Contacts_All() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_all, container, false);


    return view;
}

public void printDatabase() {

    List<ContactsObjects> contactsList = handler.getAllContacts();
    ArrayList<ContactsObjects> newContactsList = new ArrayList<ContactsObjects>();
    for (ContactsObjects cn : contactsList) {

        newContactsList.add(cn);

    }

    ListAdapter la = new ArrayAdapter<ContactsObjects>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newContactsList);

    setListAdapter(la);


}


}
```

DatabaseHandler:

```
 public List<ContactsObjects> getAllContacts() {
    List<ContactsObjects> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactsObjects>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ContactsObjects contact = new ContactsObjects();
            contact.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))));
            contact.setFirstName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstname")));
            contact.setLastName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastname")));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("phonenumber")));
            contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));

            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    return contactList;
}
```

logcat error:
1st error is at this line:

```
 List<ContactsObjects> contactsList = handler.getAllContacts();
```

2nd error is at this line:

```
  fragAll.printDatabase(); //in onCreate
```

[image: logcat]

Comment: your handler (database) never initialized in print database method of a listfragment

Comment: can you post your answer with the code that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In printDatabase() method of a listfragment (Contacts_All class)  your handler is never initialized.. You are missing this line:

```
handler = new DatabaseHandler(this, null, null, 1);
```

Comment: it works now. thanks man. I will accept your answer in 2mins since it says that I cant atm